# onNewIntent() will not fire until phone is awake

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have found some interesting behavior and do not know why or how to get around it.
The activity is a singletask activity, which means onNewIntent() is for the activity while the activity is on the top of the stack.  This works fine and well, *while the phone's screen is on*.  Once the screen is off however, the new intent is not received until the phone is "awake" and at that point the onNewIntent() is called.  If the activity is not at the top of the stack and the phone is asleep then the activity is started and the onCreate() method is called.

The Activity declared as:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
          android:launchMode="singleTask" 
          android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" >
```

The Activity is also launched with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  flag.  The intent is launched from a broadcast receiver.  If the phone is asleep and the intent is broadcast the activity wakes the phone up with these flags:

```
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON); 
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

However the activity is not created until the phone is awake when it is on the top of the stack.  Right now I am perplexed and not sure where to start.  Also my activity uses onSaveInstanceState().  The activity is a FragmentActivity and contains one fragment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However the activity is not created until the phone is awake when it
>   is on the top of the stack.

As far as i know, that's by design. The only way to wake up the phone and keep it awake is by grabbing a wake lock.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

The typical pattern is that you receive some intent to wake up your app, like the network state has changed, or whatever. In your receiver, in `onHandleIntent(),` you grab a wake lock. You start a service to do some work, and the service releases the wake lock after it is done.

In your case, the receiver that sends the intent to your activity can grab a partial wake lock, then your activity can grab a screen wake lock. Keep in mind that as long as you hold the wake lock, the phone cannot sleep ... causing it to use much more battery. Wake locks are very dangerous things for that reason.

Note that you must do the lock hand off. If you don't hold a wake lock when `onHandleIntent()` returns, the device can go right back to sleep. So it'd be something like,

```
receiver: acquire partial lock
activity: acquire screen lock
activity: release partial lock
```

You could also probably just grab the screen lock temporarily, then release it ... the screen would come on, then go off normally according to the display timeout setting.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, however wanted to avoid using a wake lock unless I absolutely had to.  When the activity is not on the top of the stack and the intent is sent when the phone is asleep the activity is started and I do not need a wake lock.  I assumed that the onNewIntent() in the same activity would follow the same behavior, but obviously not.  I am going to give the partial lock a try.

Comment: that is strange, agreed, i wouldn't think it would matter if the activity is on the top of the stack or not. let me know what you find.

Comment: No luck with the partial lock.  The activity is never called so I can not acquire a screen lock.

Comment: Got it working with a wakelock in the receiver.  Just odd that it the wake lock is only needed when activity is receiving a new intent. When not on receiving a new intent or with non standard activities setting the window flag worked just fine...thanks!

Comment: Instead of handing the lock over to the activity you should be able to just acquire it for a minimum period, with `acquire(milliseconds)`. According to the doco: "Ensures that the device is on at the level requested when the wake lock was created. The lock will be released  after the given timeout expires". So, even if the variable has gone out of scope or finalized, the device should still be awake for the acquired period. I used the flags FULL_WAKE_LOCK and ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, and acquired it for 1000ms.

Comment: I don't get that from the doc you quoted. In general it's a bad idea to depend on code completing or reaching a certain point my a particular time.